# Show Div When Hover Based on ID in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a div that when i want hover to it, it will show other div. However, my first div is dynamic, it has an ID. So how will i able to hover to ID based on its ID?

It should be `@mouseenter="hoverService{{services.id}} = true"` but it causes error. So i made the code below to just static.

Here's my code below:

```
<template>
    <div
    class="col-md-3"
    v-for="(services, index) in servicesFiltered"
    :key="index"
    @mouseenter="hoverService = true"
    @mouseleave="hoverService = false"
    >
    <div class="service_background" v-if="hoverService">
        <div class="mb-1" v-for="(sub_services, index) in services.menu_items" :key="index">
        <router-link
            :to="{ path: `/${sub_services.data}`}"
        >
            <a
            href="#"
            class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100 services_button"
            >{{sub_services.text }}</a>
        </router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      hoverService: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

https://codesandbox.io/s/y7p9qyyovz

You need to maintain hover for each item you can not manipulate using single variable for multiple items.